# Which are the default Ubuntu 14.10 gtk, icons, cursors and windows themes?

Tags: unity, themes, 14.10, default

If I'll know that, I'll be able to remove the others via Terminal.
I have a Unity desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> GTK Theme - Ambiance
>
> Icons - Ubuntu-mono-dark
>
> Cursors - Dmz-white

Why do you want to remove the others anyway?

Comment: I'd like to remove them because I'm a newbie. A few days ago I was installing all along what I saw (online guides, copy-paste terminal commands) and now my system is a little messy. ;) Now, when I already know some terminal commands, I'll be able to install only what I really like.